# Wordpress Multisite brakes wp-load.php

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to write a small tool using php. This temporarily connects to one of two Wordpress systems on the same web space by loading the wp-load.php of the needed Wordpress-Installation.

Both systems are standalone multisite installations, which are not connected.
The folder structure on the server looks like this:

```
/ -> WordPress install 1
/foldername/ -> WordPress install 2
/toolname/ -> Tool
```

With Wordpress installation 1 it works just fine.
It does not work on Wordpress installation 2. The error logs give the following error:

```
[14-Apr-2022 07:25:37 UTC] PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/local/www/apache24/noexec/domainname/_offer/includes/functions.php: 596) in /usr/local/www/apache24/noexec/domainname/luxuscharter/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 79
```

But: the function on this line is a simple calculation function, which doesn't do anything relating to that problem. I think the problem is related to the specific wordpress installation. If i remove the mutlisite-data from the wp-config of Wordpress-Installation 2, it works just fine.

**UPDATE**
I managed to load the file with setting the path differently, which seems to work so far. But no i get the response that Wordpress can't etablish the database-Connection. Any ideas?

Comment: `.../ms-settings.php on line 79` is where a function was called that could not send a header - but the _reason_ for that problem is the output created at `.../functions.php: 596`, so you should check what happens there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem myself as the answer given here didn't help me.

It turned out that it was due to the subfolder installation and not, as stated here, to one of the functions or the database connection, or the header information being sent.

WP-load probably does not recognize the corresponding affiliation to the Wordpress system if it is a subfolder installation. The following steps helped me:

a) create a sunrise.php in the wp-content folder of the subfolder installation

Code:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/subfolderinstallation') === false) $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/subfolderinstallation/'; } ?>
```

b) Add to the wp-config.php install the following line:

```
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
```

c) Load both of the following files for the php-file to recognize the right paths

```
     require_once('../../luxuscharter/wp-blog-header.php');
     require_once  "../../luxuscharter/wp-load.php";
```

I'm pretty sure you don't have to do all of the steps above, but that's exactly how it worked for me.

Comment: Also, a warning to anyone using browser extensions like Stylebot for Chrome: make sure the browser extension is disabled, as it sends a header before your code can do it. This results in a very similar error (Cannot modify header information - headers already sent) - I just wasted an hour debugging to figure this out.